# Why is absolute positioning not working?

Tags: html, css

I want to keep my footer at the bottom:

```
body, html{position:relative;}
footer{position:absolute;}
```

but still things are weird. The `footer` doesn't get placed at the very bottom even when `bottom: 0;` is done. Can anyone help me debug this?
[JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/xunadijoxa/edit?html,css,output) and [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/c0y6dx6j/).

Comment: Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: What is wrong with posting the relevant info within the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set height or min height to your body element to cover the hole page. Then the footer goes to bottom of screen.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  position:relative;
  min-height:100vh;
}

footer{background-color:blue;width:100%;height:50px;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
```

```html
<body>
<header id="header">
      <ul id="logo">
        <li><i></i></li>
      </ul>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="login.php">login</a></li><!--
          --><li><a href="signup.php">signup</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main id="main">
      <div id="login-form">
        
        <form method="POST" onsubmit="return ValidateEmail();">
          <i id="login-image"></i>
          <span id="username-container"><input type="text" name="email" required="required" class="text" placeholder="Username / Email" onkeyup="ValidateEmail()" /><br/><span id="idea"></span></span>
          <span id="password-container"><input type="password" name="password" required="required" class="text" placeholder="Password" /><span id="toggle-password"></span></span><br/>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /><a href="/">Signup now ?</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </main>


    <footer>
      <i>COPYRIGHT &copy; 2017</i>
    </footer>
  <body>
```

Comment: Please add some commentary to explain how your code fixes the problem.

Comment: Ok @Bobulous, I added the explanations.

Comment: Thank you @FarzinKanzi. It wasn't the solution that I used but it is very very close. I'll accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add width, height (and a color!) to the class.

```
footer {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0!important;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: We are just giving you idea what could be missing on your code, without your own effort and understanding, nobody can help you. Also your JSBin and JSFiddle codes are different. Having a question asked with issues will get you answers with issues.

Comment: Thank you brother. Appreciate your effort.